# O que significa := em uma function no PostgreSQL e qual diferença se usar só o =?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, funções

Um exemplo dessa questão seria se eu declarasse na função uma data e depois atualizasse essa variável assim:

```
data_inicial := date_trunc('month', (ano || mes || '-01')::timestamp);
```

Sendo ano e mês dados em formato `character` e a `data_inicial` no formato `date`;

Pra que serve o `:=` e qual diferença em usar só o `=` nesse mesmo exemplo.

Comment: Na prática, não tem diferença. Na própria [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html) explica que não há diferença. Havia diferença nas versões anteriores à versão 9.4 do  PostgreSQL.

Comment: show, obrigado!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr:** são iguais, nenhuma diferença nesse contexto.

Como pode ser visto na [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html), no assinalamento de variáveis pode ser usado tanto `=` quanto `:=`:

```
variable { := | = } expression;
```

### Um pouco de história

A sintaxe do PL/pgSQL permite o uso de `:=` e `=` há muito tempo, mas era recomendado usar sempre `:=`, e o `=` era um padrão não documentado até a versão 9.4 do PG ([veja que na 9.3 ou anterior mostra somente o `:=`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-statements.html)), onde passou-se a considerar oficial o uso de `=`.

Pode-se confirmar nisso no commit que fez a atualização da documentação, onde o seguinte comentário na gramática do PostgreSQL foi removido:

```
assign_operator    : '='   /* not documented because it might be removed someday */
```

Trocando por algo mais definitivo:

```
/*
* Ada-based PL/SQL uses := for assignment and variable defaults, while
* the SQL standard uses equals for these cases and for GET
* DIAGNOSTICS, so we support both.  FOR and OPEN only support :=.
*/
```

Particularmente eu prefiro o uso de `:=`, já que era o formato documentado anteriormente, acabou sendo mais amplamente adotado, mas na prática é indiferente.

### Operador de comparação

Importante ressaltar que `:=` e `=` são idênticos no contexto de *assignment*, já em comparações (e.g. IF, WHERE, LOOP, CASE, etc.) somente o `=` é válido. Como assinalamento de variáveis num contexto de comparação não é possível em PL/pgSQL, como em outras linguagens (e.g. C/C++), não há ambiguidade no uso do `=` nesses dois contextos.

Comment: show, obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Atualmente conforme a documentação ambos os símbolos `:=` e `=` usados como operadores de de atribuição possuem o mesmo significado.

> [**43.5.1. Atribuição**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#:%7E:text=Section%C2%A043.5.2.-,43.5.1.%C2%A0Assignment,-An%20assignment%20of)
>
> Uma atribuição de um valor a uma variável PL/pgSQL é escrita como:
>
> ```
> variable{ := | = } expression;
> ```
>
> Exemplos:
>
> ```sql
> tax := subtotal * 0.06;
> my_record.user_id := 20;
> my_array[j] := 20;
> my_array[1:3] := array[1,2,3];
> complex_array[n].realpart = 12.3;
> ```

Porém apenas o símbolo `=` pode ser utilizado como operador de comparação:

> [Tabela 9.1. Operadores de comparação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#:%7E:text=Table%C2%A09.1.%C2%A0Comparison%20Operators)
>
> | Operador | Descrição |
> | --- | --- |
> | `datatype < datatype→boolean` | Menor que |
> | `datatype > datatype→boolean` | Maior que |
> | `datatype <= datatype→boolean` | Menos que ou igual a |
> | `datatype >= datatype→boolean` | Melhor que ou igual a |
> | **`datatype = datatype→boolean`** | Igual |
> | `datatype <> datatype→boolean` | Não igual |
> | `datatype != datatype→boolean` | Não igual |

*No passado conforme explicado em [when to use = and := in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30981004/11379709) em versões anteriores a versão PostgreSQL 9.4 apenas o operador `:=` fazia atribuição enquanto o operador `=` era exclusivamente destinado a comparações. Informação importante para quem trabalha com sistemas legados.*

Comment: show, obrigado!